# GDB Packs Missing?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I run GDB on a program and get this after setting breakpoint main:

Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-55.el7.x86_64

What exactly does it want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you should install a debuginfo package of the program you debugged. The package's name is always like this:

```
{package-name}-debuginfo.x86_64.
```

It is the package which includes the source code of the program you used, so when you debug the program it can locate many information like source file, line number and so on.